# 1990's movie about underground prison where guards are cyborgs

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

Can you tell me the title of a movie made in the late 1980's or early 1990's where the hero is imprisoned for getting his wife pregnant on an overpopulated Earth? Unauthorized breeding is a crime.

Most of the story occurs in an underground prison that has cyborgs for guards. The guards force the prisoners to dig and expand the prison.

> The cyborg-guards are made from the babies of imprisoned pregnant women. The babies grow into adults with cyborg-implants in them. He and his friends defeat the computer that controls the prison, escape to the surface, and get away in a truck with his wife while she is in labor.

Comment: Sounds very much like Fortress with Christopher Lambert... Had some cyborgs but more controlled the prisoners with explosives shoved down their throats can could be used to track them, suffer pain  and make em go kaboom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1992 film [Fortress](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106950/?ref_=nv_sr_2), directed by Stuart Gordon and written by Troy Neighbors and Steven Fweinberg.

It featurs Christoffer Lambert as John Henry Brennick and Loryn Locklin as his wife, Karen B. Brennick, with Kurtwood Smith as the *enhanced* prison director Poe.

Plot summary from IMDb:

> In a futuristic USA, it's forbidden to give birth to more than one child for each woman. As usual, you can escape to Mexico to avoid the authorities in USA, which is exactly what John and Karen Brennick were trying to do when Karen is pregnant with her second child (their first child was born dead). When they think they have made it they are discovered and put to prison (for 31 years), a modern prison called the "Fortress" where the prisoners are controlled by lasers, neutron-cannons, cameras, mind-scanners and electronic pain-causing devices in their stomachs. With those odds, John still plans to escape with his wife.
>    <sub>*- Summary written by IMDb user [Lars J. Aas](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?plot_author=Lars%20J.%20Aas%20%3Clarsa%40colargol.edb.tih.no%3E&view=simple&sort=alpha&ref_=ttpl_pl_2)*</sub>